# Removing input value on focus when the value was dynamically set before

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

With the code below, the value of `.srch-inpt` is changing according to the selected option's class.

I need to remove the value of the `.srch-inpt` on focus and have it back on blur.

The code I've written does not work properly.

```js
//Changing search value on select-box option change
$(function(){
    $('.srchopts').change(function () {
        var optclass = "";
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            optclass += $(this).attr('class');
        });
        if (optclass == 'bookopt' || 'thesisopt' ) {
            $('.srch-inpt').val('Title/ Author/ Keyword/ ISBN');
        }
        if (optclass == 'articleopt' ) {
            $('.srch-inpt').val('Title/ Author/ Keyword/ Doi');
        }
        if (optclass == 'journalopt' ) {
            $('.srch-inpt').val('Title/ ISSN');
        }
    });
    $('.srch-inpt').focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('defaultValue'))
            $(this).val('');
        }).blur(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '')
            $(this).val( $(this).attr('defaultValue') );
        });     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="srchopts">
    <option class="bookopt">Book Option</option>
    <option class="articleopt">Article Option</option>
    <option class="thesisopt">Thesis Option</option>
    <option class="journalopt">Journal Option</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="" class="srch-inpt" value="Title / Author / Keywords / ISBN" defaultValue="" />
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UJaMH/)

Comment: FYI use html5 data attribute `data-default-value` or the data object `$(this).data('defaultValue')` but not an invalid attribute `defaultValue`

Comment: my DOCTYPE is not HTML5 so I used your second solution, but it didn't work also ..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.srch-inpt').data('defaultValue','My default value').focus(function () {
    if (this.value === $(this).data('defaultValue')) this.value = "";
}).blur(function () {
    if (!this.value.length) this.value = $(this).data('defaultValue');
}).blur();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gfR9W/)

Comment: this code individually works, but due to the codes before this part, there are some conflicts.. check this fiddle plz ~> http://jsfiddle.net/UJaMH/

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer with the point A. Wolff mentioned.
As we don't have "DefaultValue" attribute in new jQuery, I have to create it by myself, and update it's value each time I change **.srch-inpt** value.

So, this is my new jQuery piece of code :

```
//Changing search value on select-box option change
$(function(){
    $('.srchopts').change(function () {
        var optclass = "";
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            optclass += $(this).attr('class');
        });
        if (optclass == 'bookopt' || 'thesisopt' ) {
            $('.srch-inpt').val('Title/ Author/ Keyword/ ISBN');
        }
        if (optclass == 'articleopt' ) {
            $('.srch-inpt').val('Title/ Author/ Keyword/ Doi');
        }
        if (optclass == 'journalopt' ) {
            $('.srch-inpt').val('Title/ ISSN');
        }

        $('.srch-inpt').attr('defaultValue', $('.srch-inpt').val());
    });
    $('.srch-inpt').focus(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('defaultValue') == '')
            $(this).attr('defaultValue', $(this).get(0).defaultValue);


        if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('defaultValue'))
            $(this).val('');
    }).blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '')
            $(this).val( $(this).attr('defaultValue') );
    });     
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UJaMH/1/)